# Buffer is allocated from a shared heap for the process that is 64 KB in size?

Tags: c#, winapi, heap-memory, pinvoke

Would anyone be kind enough to translate this sentence for someone blissfully ignorant of unmanaged code and intricacies of memory management?

> The storage for this buffer is
>   allocated from a shared heap for the process that is 64 KB in size.
>   The maximum size of the buffer will depend on heap usage.

It's present on few dozen MSDN pages, e.g. [WriteConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms687401.aspx), but I can't find any API that would calculate the maximum size such array is allowed to be before blowing up, empirically I can tell it's somewhere between 61 and 62.5 KB (by calling 64, 63, 62 etc until it stops setting `DllImport`'s `SetLastError`). Is there anything like `GetTotalHeapSize` (if it's not a const 64KB independent of Windows version, platform architecture, defaults, etc) and something like `GetCurrentHeapInUse` available? How would one get the max bytes I can pass to that and other P/Invoked methods?

Comment: Here is a hunch. The heap is very likely to be on a 64k boundary. If so, call `myptr=malloc(1)` and inspect the value of `myptr & 0xFFFF`. It will be very close to the amount of space used - the amount left will be approximately 64k minus that number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how heaps work.  They don't keep track of the largest allocation you can make.  It is unpredictable because a heap can get fragmented.  Free blocks may be interleaved with allocated ones.  Releasing a single small allocation may suddenly double the available space for example.   Unmanaged heaps don't have the luxury of a managed heap, they cannot get compacted.  Albeit that the .NET Large Object Heap has this problem too.  There is no function to measure the largest available space, it is impossible to make that thread-safe.

Nothing you can do but *try* to allocate and deal with the consequences if you can't.

Comment: Thanks, I find it strange that there are a dozen public APIs that require array param of an unknown length, or less-than-64kb-but-not-sure-how-much-less to be specific. Am I correct assuming that event though 61kb array works on my machine if I hardcode 60kb it's still not guaranteed to work on other devices/platforms? And [HeapQueryInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa366703.aspx) and [HeapSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa366706.aspx) functions just sound useful but not gonna help to get that magic exact number of bytes?

Comment: This heap is an unusual one.  It is an implementation detail for consoles and isn't exposed at all.  The only reason you heard of it is because it is so small so Microsoft had to say something about it to explain the common errors.  The console api is quirky that way.  Afaik it is a solved problem anyway, this restriction only exists in older Windows versions.  The sane thing to do is to just not try to push the limit.  WriteConsole will work just as well with small buffers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'solved anyway'? Here's a managed snippet blowing up with the same `Not enough storage is available` on latest OS/hardware...
`Console.WindowHeight = 100; Console.BufferWidth = 1000; Console.MoveBufferArea(0, 0, Console.BufferWidth, 16, 0, 0);`

Comment: That works fine on Windows 8.  I can change the buffer to 32766 x 32766 without a problem.  Going higher is verboten by the .NET wrapper.

Comment: You're right, tried http://pastebin.com/pvbgC6gV on WinServ2012 and works fine, but blows up on Win7x64 at 16.